# Libvirt allow hook to fork

Tags: linux, libvirt, virt-manager, hook, vfork

If I have following Libvirt hook in `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/hook.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $1 == "SEARCH_FOR_ME" ]]; then
    while true; do
        sleep 1
    done
fi

bash /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/hook.sh SEARCH_FOR_ME &
disown $!

touch /tmp/test123

exit 0
```

Now when I start any of my VMs this hook gets called and what I expected to happen is that a new process will be spawned and will run alongside VM.

What actually happens is that libvirt for some reason knows that forked process is still running. Note that `/tmp/test123` is being created.

It seems that original bash script is being suspended.

```
 2438 root        20   0     0     0     0 Z   0.0  0.0  0:00.00 bash
 2439 root        20   0  4396  3200  2944 S   0.0  0.0  0:00.04 bash /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/hook.sh SEARCH_FOR_ME
```

Also while running the same hook in my terminal I can't observe the same behavior.

nohup works the same way and doesn't fix this issue.

My system:

```
Artix Linux (OpenRC 0.53)
Hyprland WM (Wayland)
Libvirtd + Virt Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I couldn't find solution in bash. Made a quick wrapper in python that works as a good substitute.

```
import subprocess
import sys

args = sys.argv
args.pop(0)

proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
print(proc.pid)
```

Called:

```
/usr/bin/python ./wrapper.py bash /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/hook.sh SEARCH_FOR_ME
```

Note that this wrapper returns PID by printing it to stdout.